# PHP Form with process on same page?

Tags: php, forms

I've created a form on my page and from the tutorials im following it says I have to have a second page with all the php processing in, is it not possible to keep the php on the same page and when the user hits submit the form is sent?

Why isnt this working on my process page? It doesnt echo anything :S

```
<?php 
$kop = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['severity']);
$loc = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['location']};
$summary = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['summary']);
$name = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['name']);
$email = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['email']);

echo $kop;
echo $loc; 
echo $summary; 
echo $name; 
echo $email;
?>
```

Comment: It's possible, but it's usually more readable to separate the steps. It's up to you though

Comment: I somewhat agree with Pekka, however I would strongly disagree when it comes to things like checkout pages. There are numerous studies that show single-page checkouts that use AJAX reduce page abandonment rates.

Comment: post form html check if method is post not get like in my answer <form name="myfrom" action="" method="post">

Comment: thankyou, it works without the real escape stirng though

Comment: http://www.html-form-guide.com/php-form/php-form-action-self.html

Answer (score 10):

You can check in the same file if the submit button is pressed. (http://pastebin.com/8FC1fFaf)

```
if (isset($_POST['submit'])) 
{ 
    // Process Form
}
else
{
    // Show Form
}
```

Regarding form checking, you can save the user input, and if one of their data is unvalid you can echo the old data back and show the form again.

edit: As PeeHaa stated, you need to leave the action blank though ;)

Comment: Agree + vote. However, this still requires a post action, and one of the considerations was "keep the php on the same page and when the user hits submit the form is sent". Hence see my response regarding AJAX.

Comment: Yep Aaron Newton, i think he didn't meant to avoid the reload though ;) Just to prevent the processing in another page.

Comment: There is a full code example at http://www.html-form-guide.com/php-form/php-form-action-self.html

Answer (score 4):

Yes it is possible. As adviced by Pekka, it's not really suggested to do so. But here is how it can be done.

Simply using the isset method to check if the form has been posted. So say in your form you have the follwing input:

```
<input type="text" name="age" />
```

At the top of your php script you can use the following to know if the form has been submitted and thus process it.

```
<?php if(isset($_POST["age"])) { 
    //do processing
} ?>
```

Hope this helps ;)

Comment: What a pointless downvote... This answer is fine ElGabbu. I've fixed a typo in your `<input>` line however - it needed an extra quote.

Comment: Thank you very much Jam. Sometimes the downward votes are truly depressing :)

Answer (score 2):

It is possible to let the same script process the form.

If you want to do this just leave the action blank.

However If you want to process the form without the page being reloaded you have to use Javascript.

Comment: @Jam: Thanks. I don't mind getting downvoted. I just wanted to know what was wrong with it.

Comment: It looks like the downvote trolls are about... @ElGabbu has one too, and his is a good answer as well!

Comment: Seems this way indeed. Btw (this is from my point of view ofc) i don't think that the TS meant to prevent a page reload. But time will tell ;)

Answer (score 2):

> is it not possible to keep the php on the same page and when the user hits submit the form is sent?

It sounds like you are describing AJAX. Example: http://www.elated.com/res/File/articles/development/javascript/jquery/slick-ajax-contact-form-jquery-php/

This is using the jQuery framework - there are a number of frameworks for doing this (such as YUI) which could do this equally as well. You could write this yourself to learn how it all works, but IHMO this would be reinventing the wheel. Here is a decent tutorial on creating AJAX forms with jQuery:

http://www.elated.com/articles/slick-ajax-contact-form-jquery-php/

Answer (score 1):

```
<form name="myfrom" action="" method="post">
 Username: <input type="text" name="user" id="username" />
 <input type="submit" name="submit_form" value="Submit" />
</form> 

<?php if($_POST['submit_form'] == "Submit"){
       echo "do something";
       }
?>
```

Comment: If somebody submits the form, and then later hits refresh on their browser, the form gets resubmitted. How do you avoid this?